# What happens when 2 content models in Alfresco overlap?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

When trying to update a Custom Content Model in Alfresco I decided to upload and activate a new copy and delete the old one. I found out this doesn't work.

So my question is what will happen now and how can I fix this?

What will happen where the two content models are the same?

What will happen where the two content models define the same aspect, but differently?

Does one take precedent over the other?

Would editing the 2 in the properties to be identical get around the problem?

Starting from scratch with this repository is an undesirable option at this time. I'm looking for the simplest solution possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not simple as that. If you already have some documents or folder associated with a model, you can't delete it without breaking your datas.

Also, Alfresco doesn't support multiple declarations of a model or type or aspect. If it's the case it doesn't start.

The only way you have to upload a new version of your model is by uploading a version containing ONLY added properties, types or aspects. If your new model's version contains modificated or deleted properties, types or aspects, you will have to migrate each node programaticaly.

Comment: So from what I'm understanding. Does Alfresco do something like a diff on the model? 

So far even with the multiple models there, we haven't had any issues. I assume because we made the models identical?

Comment: Sorry I was unprecise. Alfresco doesn't support models which have an identical namespace. 
If, for example, you change the namespace of your second model, even if the name of the model is the same, the couple "namespace:modelname" will different and so, Alfresco is agree with that; it's another model.
This is a solution.

If you keep the same namespace, the new model have to be named differently. Inside the model you should be able to have the same types, properties ...

So, to answer your question, I should verify in source code but AFAIK Alfresco will just verify the couple "NS":"name"